# Social sharing links without addthis etc?

Tags: javascript, social-networking

Im wanting to ditch addthis because it slows my page load time considerably.
The main benefit off addthis to me was that it detected the page being shared and the user wouldn't have to copy and paste the page link.

If i go with the stand alone links the big services like G plus offer, you need to manually edit the code on each page with the link to the page being shared.

Eg: https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.site.com/page.htm

This would be very time consuming.

Is there a way to script something so that it appends the page that its on into the link for g plus, twitter, flickr etc?

Or any other known way to automate the process?

Answer (score 0):

To append page URL dynamically at the end of your G+ URL:

This will append your page URL without protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var GooglePlusURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname 
  </script>
```

OR
this will append your page URL with protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var GooglePlusURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + window.location.href
 </script>
```

This way separate GooglePlus Url will be created for every page.

Add the code in a header/footer file or some common file that is used on every page. This way your javascript code will get appended on every page automatically.

In most cases, header and footers are common in all pages and hence these files are included on every page. However, it depends on the framework you are using and the coding standard that you are following.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I might not as been as clear as i should have been. The link offered by g plus is https://plus.google.com/share?url=. That link wont pick up the page nor site its being clicked from. I could put https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.site.com in the link but that would only share the homepage link from every page the link is on. I need a way to have the specific page the g plus share link is clicked on to append for eg: www.site.com/page-im-on-now to https://plus.google.com/share?url=

Comment: Sorry i got you now. I put the js in my page and nothing is happening.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? If your site is live, you can post the link here

Comment: There are some text links at the start of the pages image gallery and the js is at bottom of page. If you require a condensed version of the page the let me know.